# Bootstrap datepicker display month & year menus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

In Bootstrap datepicker, I would like to have the Month & year menus as in jquery Ui datepicker [image]

But in [Bootstrap date picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/), there is no month & year menus and we have to click the month to change the year.

Is it possible to display both Month and Year Menus in the [Bootstrap date picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)?

Comment: I will ask the obvious. Why not just use the jQuery datepicker? It works like you want it to work.

Answer (score 8):

```
var datePick=$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
datePick.click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 4):

I think [dhtmlxCalender](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/samples/01_init/02_attach_to_input_with_icon.html) would be a far far better option for you in this case.

An example code for you-

```js
var myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["calendar","calendar2","calendar3"]);
```

```css
#calendar,#calendar2,#calendar3
{
    border: 1px solid #909090;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/codebase/dhtmlx.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/codebase/dhtmlx.css"/>

<div style="position:relative;height:280px;">
   <input type="text" id="calendar">
   <input type="text" id="calendar2">
   <input type="text" id="calendar3">
</div>
```

A Codepen.IO example is [***given here by me***](http://codepen.io/abrarjahin/pen/vGYrvv).

Output will be like this-

[image]

Moreover every part of this date picker is easily customizable (CSS).

---

### Another Way is using Bootstrap Datepicker-

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $('#example1').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
 });  

});
```

```html
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--JS-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


  <div class="container">
   <input  type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="example1">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link that you might have the same issue: [Bartosz Kopiński DatePicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/145)

```
$('.date').datepicker({
  "format": "yyyy-mm",
  'startView': 1
}).on('changeMonth', function(e) {
   var dp = $(e.currentTarget).data('datepicker');
   dp.date = e.date;
   dp.setValue();
   dp.hide();
});

$('.yearpicker').datepicker({
 "format": "yyyy",
 'startView': 2
}).on('changeYear', function(e) {
  var dp = $(e.currentTarget).data('datepicker');
  dp.date = e.date;
  dp.setValue();
  dp.hide();
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I think

http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-Date-Picker-for-Bootstrap.html

This will help u a lot.

Code-

Script

```
<script src="js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

Try this.